# Redirect to previous page with php

Tags: php, html, post

The submit button is in `contact-us.html`, the code is in `contact-us.php`.

I tried to use the `header('Location: example');` with no luck... (I tried using the URL of the page as well: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/contact-us.html');` )

Any thoughts?

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $recipient="example@gmail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["firstname"];
    $senderlast=$_POST["lastname"];
    $senderemail=$_POST["senderemail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $mailBody="First Name: $sender\nLast Name: $senderlast\nEmail: $senderemail\n\nMessage: $message";

    header('Location: /contact-us.html'); /*Something Wrong?*/

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderemail>")
}
```

Comment: you want to send the user back to the contact us.html? page after you've sent the email?

Comment: Yes!! when the button is pressed it goes to the php page and stays there

Comment: Does the mail send? Could be that `if($_POST['submit'])` is `false` and the header is never set.

Comment: yes the mail works fine, i can receive all emails. only the redirect bit doesnt work...

Comment: You do realize that the header is being send before the mail function, i hope. This will mean that your mail will never be send if this works

Comment: yes dorvalla is right

Comment: where does it go? does it stays blank or give an error? is your php page not in the same directory as the html?

Comment: you have to use mail upper and header in after mail function and without / also.

Comment: i moved the header in different places before.. it looks like it is being skipped.. i do receive the emails which means that the mail part works...

Comment: no errors or something, just stays at a blank page example.com/contact-us.php . and yes both files are in the same location/directory

Comment: @Dorvalla - That's actually not true. The code will continue to execute unless you explicitly end execution (with `exit;` for example). As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30430945/3760604).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look towards the referer? PHP has a function for that.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

This means that if it comes from the cnotact.html, it will look how it came there and refers back. Easy to use if you have a second contact form on another page.

I need to add that though that this may not work via secure pages. (so if your run it via https) and its possible that the header may be able to be hijacked (especially if the browser did not send the request).

Comment: This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: I am aware of this, (hence i modified the answer a tat) but the litteral answer to this question is just that

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

I recommend using `$_SESSION` to store previous url like this:

> page1.php

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['previous'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]. $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

> page2.php

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['previous'] !== '') {
        header('Location: '. $_SESSION['previous']);
    }
```

`$_SESSION` kind of works like cookies, but a lot better. Easier to use as it's just using an array - more info can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a button with the `submit` name attribute? if yes maybe try this :

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $recipient="example@gmail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["firstname"];
    $senderlast=$_POST["lastname"];
    $senderemail=$_POST["senderemail"];
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'From: $sender <$senderemail>' . "\r\n";
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $mailBody="First Name: $sender\nLast Name: $senderlast\nEmail: $senderemail\n\nMessage: $message";


    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, $header)){

        header('Location:contact-us.html'); /*Something Wrong?*/
    }
}
```

if no then your code never enters the if block

Answer (score 0):

try using JavaScript `window.location` to redirect 
Note : wrap `window.location.href('contact-us.html');` into script tag

example :

```
echo "<script>window.location.href('contact-us.html');</script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
header('Location:  contact-us.html'); /*Something Wrong?
```

Comment: use it without /

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16845979)

Comment: @sarcom While it's not a great answer (possibly not even useful), it is an answer. Please read [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) before doing more reviews like this